# EFCore - Get specific DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to receive with class/table name as argument same DbSet as:

```
context.Table
```

Regards,
XeonBloomfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to receive with class/table name as argument
>   Yes you can.

You can use `Set()` which would require that passing your table string parameter, you must get the Type from your assembly.

```
 context.Set<TypeFromTableStringParameter>() ...
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you